# Spring Rest Error 404 when accessing the mapped URL

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

These are my classes:

### AppConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "jp.co.sample.ai")
public class AppConfig {

}
```

### AppInitializer

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

### UserController

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List getUserList(){
        return userRepo.findAll();
    }

}
```

### UserRepository

```
@Component
public class UserRepository {

private static List<User> userList;
{
    userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    userList.add(new User("tk001", "ten", "kin"));
    userList.add(new User("tk002", "ten2", "kin2"));
    userList.add(new User("tk003", "ten3", "kin3"));

}

    public List findAll(){ return userList; }
```

### My project structure is like this

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2rNa.png)

**I run this project via Tomcat but i get error 404**

*http://localhost:8080/users*

*http://localhost:8080* **<< gives me the default index.jsp**

**Please help! Thanks.**

Comment: You say you're getting a 404 when running on Tomcat. Do you mean deployed as a war file, or just started straight from the IDE?

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox i am actually using intellij so, i built the exploded artifact with the Tomcat.. and yes.. i tried both, deployed from Tomcat using a war file, and runned through the IDE.. same error.. 404 :(

Comment: So, in IntelliJ IDEA, did you just start the application (via the button or a shortcut), or did you first build your application as a war, started a local tomcat, and then deployed the generated war-file in your local tomcat?

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox my project is a maven one. First, i clean install.. Then added Tomcat Server.. Then on the configuration of Tomcat Server, there is this, build artifact, and i selected the exploded one.. well, this artifact is automatically built when i added Restful Web Service on my project framework support.. I checked the classes on the artifact, and it is also updated. :( i wonder its error 404. :( I run the project through Tomcat on IDE

Comment: Add @RequestMapping(value = "/")   annotation on UserController

Comment: Right now, i tried deploying the war file.. from tomcat manager, and still error 404

Comment: What is the exact name of your generated file (when you clean install)?

Comment: @Deep still error 404. :(

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox well, when i clean and install, the classes goes to the "target" folder...

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox but when i run the Tomcat, the exploded war file is created/updated... in a separate "out" folder

Comment: Go to your tomcat/webapps directory. What files (and directories) do you see?

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox At first these are the only folders visible: docs, examples, host-manager, manager... But when i uploaded my rar file on localhost:8080/manager/html..... the war folder and the .war file is included on the webapps folder.. i tried http://localhost:8080/sampleai_20180705_war/users << but still error 404

Comment: Where does your Spring application start? I cannot see a Spring starting class in your project structure. Like this: https://imgur.com/Ft8YYpc

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox im not using Spring boot.. I actually tried to copy the implementation here on this project: https://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-4-mvc-rest-example-json/ << This project runs on me.. however, when i started a new project... i only get error 404 when accessing to /users

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox that tutorial uses java version 1.7.. i used 1.8 and uses Tomcat 8.5 :/ i wonder if thats the problem.. i also tried extending the base packages to "<package>.*" still no use

Comment: You are returning a List of user not a jsp page. So if you want to print a list of user on that mapping you should use `@ResponseBody` annotation. eg: `public @ResponseBody List getUserList() {......` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I already solved this issue.

On intellij IDEA, the artifact creation is created in a different folder named as "out".. this has the different folder name as the default folder if i clean and install, "target" folder.

So, i edited the configuration path of my exploded artifact into the "target" folder.. and added all the lib and classes folders. It worked that way.